# adding LinkedIn article pages as a property in Google Search Console

Tags: linkedin-api, google-search-console

Is there a way to add LinkedIn article pages as properties in Google Search Console ?

This is possible with Squarespace, Wordpress, medium, etc. We should be able to give LinkedIn the code generated by GSC when adding a property, then submit the code to LinkedIn to be added to our company or profile page. In that way articles are indexed by Google search immediately.

When I post articles on LinkedIn it can be months before they are indexed by Google search, if at all. It's not a rankings issue, I test independently of rankings by searching:

article title site:linkedin.com

We would not need to depend on Microsoft and Google to cooperate if we could add directly to GSC pages as a property we own and/or are responsible for.

-Jeff

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @John Conde, that would be fine, except I'm following LinkedIn procedures as they document [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/10294264)

If there is a better way to get an answer out of LinkedIn -- as it's their responsibility to offer functionality compatible with GSC -- I'm all for it. Otherwise I'm hopeful that someone in the community has a workaround

Comment: LinkedIn gives specific instructions for using StackOverflow [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/53170)

Comment: I have the same question. It would be trivial for Linkedin to add the ability to add a meta tag to a company or article page. If you look at the page source, an extra tag wouldn't exactly slow it down, War & Peace is already hidden in there.

Comment: I can update this, in Dec2020 I e-mailed Microsoft VP Gyanda Sachdeva directly about this issue, and there was some good discussion with her group. They were already aware of the issue. No time-frame for a fix though